# Polynomials all of whose roots are rational

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, roots

I have two questions about the class of integer-coefficient polynomials all of whose roots are rational.

**Q1**. Is there some way to recognize such a polynomial from its coefficients $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$?

I am aware of the [rational-root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which says that each rational root is of the form $\pm p/q$, where $p$ is a factor of $a_0$ and $q$ a factor of $a_n$.

**Q2**. Has this class of polynomials been studied in its own right?

In other words, is this class interesting?  I can see it has at least a monoid structure,
as the product of two such polynomials also has all rational roots.

These are naive questions, well out of my expertise.  Thanks in advance for educating me!

**Update**. The discussion at MathOverflow (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97307/)) concluded that **Q1** can be answered in polynomial time, using methods in the famous
Lenstra, Lenstra, Lovász paper, "Factoring polynomials with rational coefficients."

Comment: This class is bijective with the class of all pairs $(A,X)$ where $A$ is an integer and $X$ is a finite multiset of rational numbers. Whether that is a useful fact, I don't know.

Comment: @Hurkyl: yes, but it doesn't appear to be particularly easy to compute this bijection in one direction.

Comment: Sturm's Theorem gives you a way of telling how many distinct real roots there are without computing them and can be used to locate roots. So that can be done from the coefficients. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, yes. So one can view the question as seeking an equivalent of Sturm's Theorem for rational roots.

Comment: I've now crossposted to [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97307/).

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97307/).