# Existence of rational sequence such that a polynomial is split over $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, polynomials, rational-numbers

> Does there exist a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ of rationals such that for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$, $a_n\neq 0$ and the polynomial $a_0+a_1X+\cdots+a_nX^n$ is split over $\Bbb{Q}$?

I was asked this question by myself but I am unable to find a solution, does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Well the sequence must be finite. Then how about $a_{0}=1$, $a_{1}=1$ and $a_{n}=0$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Comment: A related (terrible) question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492326/rational-roots-of-polynomials

Comment: You had me at "I was asked this question by myself".

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively define the coefficients in order that 
$$ p_n(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n $$
has a root in $x=n$, for instance:
$$ a_n = -\frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_j\, n^j.$$
If you meant that every $p_n(x)$ must *completely* split over $\mathbb{Q}$ for a sequence with infinite non-zero terms, it is believed that there is no chance, but the linked question is still open.

Comment: *Split* = *factors into linear factors* = *all the roots are rational*

Comment: I just realized the possibility of such interpretation, but in this case the question is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492326/rational-roots-of-polynomials.

Comment: It is, indeed, close to being an exact duplicate. Apparently here we won't insist that the roots should be distinct.