# How to show that the polynomilal $\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac 1{3^{k^2}}x^k$ has $n$ distinct real roots for any positive integer $n$ ?

Tags: polynomials, roots

From this [Rational roots of polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492326/rational-roots-of-polynomials) ; How might we show that the polynomilal $\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac 1{3^{k^2}}x^k$ has $n$ distinct real roots $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: Now I'm curious where this problem came from - it's extremely similar to problem B4 on the 2014 Putnam!

Comment: @GregMartin: The problem came form the link I have given ...!

Answer (score 5):

Evaluating the polynomial at $x=-3^{2m}$ for $0\le m\le n$ yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{3^{k^2}} (-3^{2m})^k = (-1)^m 3^{m^2} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{m-k} 3^{-(m-k)^2}.
$$
In the sum on the right-hand side, the $k=m$ term equals $1$, while the sum of all the other terms is less than $1$ in absolute value (one can show). Therefore the sign of the polynomial at $-3^{2m}$ is equal to $(-1)^m$. Since this is true for the $n+1$ points $m=0,1,\dots,n$, the polynomial must vanish at least $n$ times.